# Calling an operator function in a class in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, operator-keyword

Learning C++, I got an operator function in a class but don't know how to call it:

```
class Getbytes
{
public:
      Getbytes();

      int operator() (unsigned char* C1, unsigned char* C2)
       {do something to C1 and C2 and return int; };
}

main ()
{

 Getbyes myBytes;

//Here, how to call the "operator() (unsigned char* C1, unsigned char*C2)"?
 myBytes??  

}
```

Comment: A function-call operator makes objects callable as functions, so you simply "call" the object like any other function.

Comment: Your `main` is lacking a return type. `main` *must* be declared with a return type and the return type *must* be `int`. You are also missing a semicolon after the closing `}` of the class definition. On the other hand the semicolon doesn't belong after a function definition. So the `;` after the closing `}` of the `operator()` overload does not belong there.

Answer (score 4):

You call it as `myBytes();` or `myBytes.operator();` if you want to be verbose about it.

Of course you also need to pass the arguments the function needs. Like `myBytes("foo", "bar");`

Answer (score 2):

You can call it like

```
Getbytes myBytes;

unsigned char s1[] = "Hello";
unsigned char s2[] = "World";

myBytes( s1, s2 );
```

or

```
myBytes.operator()( s1, s2 );
```

If the operator does not change the object itself of the class Getbytes then it should be declared like

```
int operator() (unsigned char* C1, unsigned char* C2) const;
```